# how to escape special regular expression characters in oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

**How to escape special characters of regular expression pattern in Oracle?**

For example I need a function which traslates

`some.string[with(special)reg-exp]characters`

to

`some\.string\[with\(special\)reg\-exp\]characters`.

In PHP I would use preg_escape(). Is there Oracle counterpart?

Why I am doing this?

I am trying to write a pl/sql function that checks if a `string` is on the `list,of,string,elements`.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION list_contains(needle_    IN VARCHAR2,
                       haystack_  IN VARCHAR2,
                       separator_ IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',')
RETURN INTEGER
  IS
BEGIN
  IF regexp_like(haystack_, '(^|' || separator_ || ')' || needle_ || '(' || separator_ || '|$)') THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END list_contains;
```

The function basicly works:

```
list_conains('eve','john,eve,maria,steve') => 1
```

The problem is when I try to call it with weird values of `needle_` or `separator_`, such as `.` or other strings that have special meaning in regular expressions.

list_conains('eve','john.maria.steve','.') => 1

As you see, there is no eve on the list, but the `.` matches the `t` letter of the steve name, so the function incorrectly returns `1`.

I know that I can replace the dots manually, but there still are plenty other regex special characters that will interfere and I would rather not try to list all the characters myself.

How to escape the needle_ and separator_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you don't need regular expressions for this. You can use the simple LIKE.

```
IF separator_ || haystack_ || separator_ LIKE '%'||separator_||needle_||separator_||'%' THEN
   RETURN 1;
ELSE
   RETURN 0;
END IF;
```

Edit: If `%` or `_` itself is the separator_, then it necessary to escape them.

```
IF separator_ = '%' OR separator_ = '_'
THEN
  separator_ := '\' || separator_;
END IF;

IF separator_ || haystack_ || separator_ LIKE
     '%' || separator_ || needle_ || separator_ || '%' ESCAPE '\'
THEN
  RETURN 1;
ELSE
  RETURN 0;
END IF;
```

Comment: Thank you. That is good idea. I don't know how could I not see this. It seems that 11g and it's new features has spoiled me. I'll use your suggestion. But for future use, question still open for answers.

Comment: Your solution after edit is not perfect, but I have made something based on your idea. 

`IF separator_ || haystack_ || separator_ LIKE
     '%' ||
     REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(separator_ || needle_ || separator_, '\', '\\'), '%', '\%'), '_', '\_') || '%'
   ESCAPE '\' THEN`... 

I did that to ensure that both needle_ and separator_ are escaped safely. I had also escape the escape character, to be sure that if needle_ contains it, it will not be treated specially.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be easiest to just escape the separator in your regexp statement.  Try this, it seemed to work for me:

```
  IF regexp_like(haystack_, '(^|\' || separator_ || ')' || needle_ || '(\' || separator_ || '|$)') THEN
```

All I changed was the slash in front of the separators in your string construction.

Comment: While this would work on some cases, there are still chancess, that the needle_ would contain special characters, so your answer is not a complete solution. But thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION list_contains(needle_    IN VARCHAR2,
                       haystack_  IN VARCHAR2,
                       separator_ IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',')
return number AS
  l_return_count number := 0;
BEGIN
  with haystack_ary as (
    select extractvalue(x.column_value, 'e') as val
    from xmltable ('e' passing xmlparse( content  '<e>' || replace(haystack_, separator_, '</e><e>') || '</e>')) x
  )
  select 
  --count(1)
  --return as a "bool"(1=true,0=false)
  decode(count(1), 0, 0, 1)
  into l_return_count
  from haystack_ary
  where lower(needle_) = lower(haystack_ary.val);

  return l_return_count;
END;
```

I made it case insensitive with lower function.  If you wanted, you could also trim whitespace:  `lower(trim(needle_)) = lower(trim(haystack_ary.val))`

Answer (score 0):

The following characters must be escaped:  \  ^  .  $  |  (  )  [  ] *  +  ?  {  }  ,

http://psoug.org/snippet/Regular-Expressions--Regexp-Cheat-Sheet_856.htm

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('some.string[with(special)reg-exp]characters', '([][)(}{.$*+?,|^\])', '\\\1') "REGEXP_REPLACE" FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without any regular expression and escapes by **instr** function, that will **return 0** if no match and **> 0** if match.

For this works, you should add the **separator_** at the begin and at the end of **needle_** and **haystack_** before check if the **haystack_** contains **needle_**.

Proof of concept

```
select haystack_, needle_, separator_, instr(separator_||haystack_||separator_, separator_||needle_||separator_) result_, expected_
from (
    select 'john,eve,maria,steve' as haystack_ , 'eve' as needle_, ',' as separator_, '>0'as expected_ from dual union all
    select 'john,eve,maria,steve' as haystack_ , 'john' as needle_, ',' as separator_, '>0'as expected_ from dual union all
    select 'john,eve,maria,steve' as haystack_ , 'joh' as needle_, ',' as separator_, '=0'as expected_ from dual union all
    select 'john,eve,maria,steve' as haystack_ , 'steve' as needle_, ',' as separator_, '>0'as expected_ from dual union all
    select 'john,eve,maria,steve' as haystack_ , 'stev' as needle_, ',' as separator_, '=0'as expected_ from dual union all
    select 'john,eve,maria,steve' as haystack_ , 'teve' as needle_, ',' as separator_, '=0'as expected_ from dual union all
    select 'john.maria.steve' as haystack_ , 'eve' as needle_, '.' as separator_, '=0'as expected_ from dual union all
    select 'john_maria_steve' as haystack_ , 'eve' as needle_, '_' as separator_, '=0'as expected_ from dual union all
    select 'john%maria%steve' as haystack_ , 'eve' as needle_, '%' as separator_, '=0'as expected_ from dual
) t;
```

result:

```
HAYSTACK_            NEEDLE_ SEPARATOR_ RESULT_ EXPECTED_
john,eve,maria,steve eve     ,          6       >0
john,eve,maria,steve john    ,          1       >0
john,eve,maria,steve joh     ,          0       =0
john,eve,maria,steve steve   ,          16      >0
john,eve,maria,steve stev    ,          0       =0
john,eve,maria,steve teve    ,          0       =0
john.maria.steve     eve     .          0       =0
john_maria_steve     eve     _          0       =0
john%maria%steve     eve     %          0       =0
```